# Resources file can not be found from maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I am sure that this kind of question is a common one, and most likely I have (or haven't) done something and it went that bad.
So I have a maven project, lets call it GoogleSheet. (it is using the Google Sheet Api to write to the Sheets). In there I have a command
`InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/credentials_G_Sheets.json");`
which is reading the google credentials for the user/app.
Now I use that project in a different maven project. Lets call it Writer. When I run this through the IDE, everything works fine. When I export it as a jar, from withing Eclipse, I am getting an error that the inputstream is null, figuring so that it can not find the file.
The file does exist on the exported jar under

> /resources/credentials_G_Sheets.json

I am thinking that application is looking for the file under the wrong path, guessing somewhere under com/my/name/GoogleSheet.

I also tried to create the jar using maven but for some reason I am getting a strange error of
`No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?`
which I am trying to figure out as well.

Thanks in advance, Ilias

**EDIT**
Based on  JB Nizet comment, If I change my code from 
`InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/credentials_G_Sheets.json");`
to
`InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/credentials_G_Sheets.json");`
works when exported to jar, but not while using the IDE. 
I can live with it for now, but I really need this to be solved.
Thanks again

Comment: Well, your code uses the path `"/credentials_G_Sheets.json"`, but the actual path is `"/resources/credentials_G_Sheets.json"`. Fix the jar generation, or fix your code.

Comment: @JBNizet I will be damned. I am sure that this was the way it was working. Thanks a lot. Seems to be working now. Can you explain what you mean by "fix the jar generation"? you refere to my maven problem? that wouldnt fix anything would it?

Comment: @JBNizet Now it doesnt work while on IDE, but I can live with it for now. Thanks again

Comment: Are you using Maven? This sounds like a configuration issue. You file should be under /src/main/resources and anything in that folder should automatically get copied into the JAR's classes folder.

Comment: In a Maven project, resources go under src/main/resources/ Everything inside that directory is supposed to go in the jar file, but not under a directory named "resources". Your jar file generated from Eclipse doesn't respect this convention, because it puts the directory resources itself in the jar file. So you get an insonsistent behavior between the run in the IDE and the run from the classpath. You should of course use Maven to build your jar. If you can't figure out how to do that yet, then at least use the same rules as Maven when generating the jar from Eclipse.

Comment: @JBNizet OK,That makes sense, I actually thought that Eclipse and Maven Jar creators would have the same output. I have used the maven jar creator on some other projects, but on this one I am getting this JDK error. Will try to fix that. Thanks